# Alexa skill SSML talking speed

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ssml

Am a building an Alexa skill and I need to spell out a code for the user. I have wrapped the code in a say-as tag. The problem is that Alexa spells out words really fast. so fast that its basically useless. Is there anyway to vary the speed of the say as tag?

```
"<say-as interpret-as='spell-out'>" +  code + "</say-as>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. this may not be the best solution but for the moment it works. What I was doing was

```
"<say-as interpret-as='spell-out'>" +  code + "</say-as>"
```

What I ended up doing was this

```
code.split('').join(' <break/> ')
```

split takes turns the string into a char array and then join puts them back together with the break tag between each letter. you can then use the time attribute to change how long of a pause is taken.

```
<break time="3s"/>
```